# symfony multiple upload vichuploadbundle

Tags: php, symfony

im looking for multiple upload in symfony using vichuploadbundle. I also have working uploader but still for only one file. I cant find answers which solve my problem.I also tried many tutorials, but nothing worked for me. In their documentation i couldnt find answer. What should i do?

error:

```
Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File", "array" given
```

My entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=5,
     *     minMessage="Title is too short!",
     *     max=50,
     *     maxMessage="Title is too long!"
     * )
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=5,
     *     minMessage="Perex is too short!",
     *     max=100,
     *     maxMessage="Perex is too long!"
     * )
     */
    private $perex;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=500, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ProductPicture", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $pictures;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPictures()
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $pictures
     */
    public function setPictures($pictures)
    {
        $this->pictures = $pictures;
    }

    public function getAttachPictures()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setAttachPictures(array $files=array())
    {
        if (!$files) return [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!$file) return [];
            $this->attachPicture($file);
        }
        return [];
    }

    public function attachPicture(UploadedFile $file=null)
    {
        if (!$file) {
            return;
        }
        $picture = new ProductPicture();
        $picture->setImageFile($file);
        $this->addPicture($picture);
    }

    public function addPicture(ProductPicture $picture)
    {
        $picture->setProduct($this);
        $this->pictures->add($picture);
    }

    public function removePicture(ProductPicture $picture)
    {
        $picture->setProduct(null);
        $this->pictures->removeElement($picture);
    }
}
```

ProductPicture:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class ProductPicture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Product
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid valid IMAGE"
     * )
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $imageName
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
    }

}
```

Form:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('perex')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('attachPictures', FileType::class, ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the file part as an entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class ProductPicture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Product
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="path\to\your\entity\Product", inversedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid valid IMAGE"
     * )
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
         return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
         return $this->product;
    } 
}
```

And in your Product entity...

```
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="path\to\your\entity\ProductPicture", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $pictures;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getPictures()
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $pictures
     */
    public function setPictures($pictures)
    {
        $this->pictures = $pictures;
    }

    public function getAttachPictures()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setAttachPictures(array $files=array())
    {
        if (!$files) return [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!$file) return [];
            $this->attachPicture($file);
        }
        return [];
    }

    public function attachPicture(UploadedFile $file=null)
    {
        if (!$file) {
            return;
        }
        $picture = new ProductPicture();
        $picture->setImageFile($file);
        $this->addPicture($picture);
    }

    public function addPicture(ProductPicture $picture)
    {
        $picture->setProduct($this);
        $this->pictures->add($picture);
    }

    public function removePicture(ProductPicture $picture)
    {
       $picture->setProduct(null);
       $this->pictures->removeElement($picture);
   }
```

And finally in the form use...

```
->add('attachPictures', FileType::class, ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])
```

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Product::attachPicture() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile given

Comment: Actually i fixed this eror, but i am getting Error 500

Comment: Check that in top of the Product entity the use you have is not `use AppBundle\Entity\UploadedFile`, it must be `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`

Comment: Can you provide the trace error of the symfony toolbar?

Comment: It looks like a form problem... try changing `->add('attachPictures', 'file', ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])` for `->add('attachPictures', FileType::class, ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])` or `->add('attachPictures', VichFileType::class, ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])`

Comment: if you comment the line `->add('attachPictures', FileType::class, ['multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false])` did appears 500 error or loads the form?

Comment: 50 error did not appear and form was successfully loaded. Now i am getting : `Neither the property "imageFile" nor one of the methods "getImageFile()", "imageFile()", "isImageFile()", "hasImageFile()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Product".`

Comment: In Product should not be nothing about the imageFile. Just the relation to the ProductImage and it should be a ArrayCollection, so remove if you have the `->add('imageFile',...)`

Comment: @JakubStaněk  I made a mistake in the code, it is fixed now. the error is here `public function attachPicture(UploadedFile $file=null)
        {
            if (!$file) {
                return;
            }
            $picture = new ProductPicture();
            $picture->setImageFile($file);
            $this->addPicture($picture);
        }`

Comment: Edited, but still getting the same error... and i dont know what is wrong. I dont understand it now

Comment: can you copy or edit the question with your two entities, Product and ProductPicture and the form?

Comment: Okey now everything works fine! Thanks for your perfect question and for your time :). All i have to did is change the name of function

Comment: i m new pls, will you clear how you caching attachPictures form key

Comment: Is the `public function setAttachPictures` in the product entity

Answer (score 2):

**Symfony 4** working solution.

Quite more simple. Just tidy your entities, create form and [form transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

```
// src/Entity/Product.php
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Collection|ProductPicture[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ProductPicture", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $pictures;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProductPicture[]
     */
    public function getPictures(): Collection
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }

    public function addPicture(ProductPicture $picture): self
    {
        if (!$this->pictures->contains($picture) {
            $this->pictures->add($picture);
            $picture->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePicture(ProductPicture $picture): self
    {
        if ($this->pictures->contains($picture) {
            $this->pictures->removeElement($picture);
            if ($picture->getProduct() === $this) {
                $picture->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    ...
}
```

```
// src/Entity/ProductPicture.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class ProductPicture
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Product
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="pictures")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid valid IMAGE"
     * )
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    ...

    /**
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if (null !== $image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you need to create simple ProductType form:

```
// src/Form/ProductForm.php
class PictureType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add($builder->create(
                'pictures',
                FileType::class,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                ]
            )->addModelTransformer(new FilesToPicturesTransformer()))
            ->add(...);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }
```

and FilesToPicturesTransformer (data transformer):

```
// src/Form/FilesToPicturesTransformer.php
class FilesToPicturesTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($value): void
    {
        // don't need this if you build API
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value): ArrayCollection
    {
        $pictures = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($value as $file) {
            $picture = (new ProductPicture())
                ->setImageFile($file);
            if (!$pictures->contains($picture)) {
                $pictures->add($picture);
            }
        }

        return $pictures;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help  you  with this upload  bundle,  but i can  show you how it's  working in my case in  more simple  way (using simple requests, not some  fancy  bundle)

here
https://gist.github.com/poznet/e3955a48fea01d8640dafbd966c53a83

you  have

- form in view
- controller code
- trait  that is imported in service entity

This trait it's a little  mess (no attachemt  size/type check etc ) ,  but it  works.

If you  have  any questions  fell free to ask.

PS in your case if you uploading  multiple  files  you get  array , not  file class  :D